# page strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I face so strange action in my page.

I have a radio button list, according to the selection i execute specific code.

The problem is:

for example when i select option `2` then i select back option `1`.

the page maintains the state(all the drop down lists maintain their previous selections) and i need to click the link one more time to force the page to enter this condition:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    BindCamp(0);
    BindCamp(1);
}
```

**my aspx :**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_SelectedIndexChanged"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">view data</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">view report</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**My code:**

```
 protected void rbl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (rbl.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
     {
         pnl_view.Visible = true;
         pnl_stat.Visible = false;
         pnl_rep.Visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
         pnl_view.Visible = false;
         pnl_all.Visible = false;
         pnl_Dean.Visible = false;
         pnl_research.Visible = false;
         pnl_stat.Visible = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem... I'm not quite sure what the problem is from this description...

Comment: The problem is:
I have a radiobutton list (two options)when i select the second option ,it shows me a panel contains two dropdownlists (i select items from these ddl).then , when i select the other radiobutton option then go back to the previous option again, i find my ddl maintain their selections !!!(like it doesn't make any postback at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments, DLL's will always retain their values unless you manually set the selection, you set EnableViewState="false" (which disabled all viewstate then).  So I think you may need code that does:

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0; // or -1 depending on whether you want an item selected
```

Upon clicking the next radio button.

Comment: Again and again i miss some important issues, yeah it's about `viewstate`,but why when redirecting to same page doesn't maintain the state?thanks  a lot

Comment: A redirect is a GET request, whereas postbacks are POST requests.  In a POST request, it posts a __VIEWSTATE element, which is where viewstate is stored.